# Erro ao instalar biblioteca Python

Tags: python, osx, mac, pip

Tenho python 2.7.14 instalado com o pip 9.0.1 em um Macbook. Eu estava com um erro ao tentar executar o comando pip.list pelo terminal.

Verifiquei no Google que precisava editar o arquivo pip.conf, mas não encontrei. Assim, verifiquei o caminho que ele deveria estar, /Library/Application Support/pip, e crie o arquivo com o seguinte conteudo:

```
[list]
format=columns
```

Quando tento executar um comando para instalar um pacote pelo terminal, por exemplo:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: 
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version 
(_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver?

Comment: Este problema ocorria antes de você criar o `pip.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza o pip do seguinte modo:

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Esse erro está relacionado com uma alteração em todas as páginas relacionadas com Python.org: deixaram de suportar as versões 1.0 e 1.1 do TLS. Isto quer dizer que para OSX <= 10.12 só dá para usar o `pip` se for actualizado pelo método acima.

Em alternativa, esse erro também deve ser resolvido se actualizar para OSX >= 10.13.

---

Créditos para o Anupam: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/3079302